# No sé cómo iniciar sesión en el nuevo phpmyadmin 4.9.1

Tags: php, mysql

Tras leer este post https://www.google.com/amp/s/news.sophos.com/es-es/2019/09/23/descubierto-dia-cero-de-phpmyadmin-que-destroza-servidores/amp/ decidí actualizar la versión de 4.8 a 4.9.1 y ahora me pide usuario y contraseña, probé root y vacío y nada. Intenté configurar config.inc.php y no viene, en su lugar viene config.sample.inc.php, edite y añadí todo lo necesario en Autenticación type  y sigo sin poder iniciar sesión. ¿Sabéis que he de hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para poder iniciar iniciar mysql sin password**

Deten el servicio de MySql

Edita el archivo my.ini y agrega esta linea

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Ahora inicia Mysql
y logeate con root y sin password

Crea un nuevo usuario o cambiale el password a root

Vuelve a detener MySql

Quita la line que agregaste

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Inicia Mysql y ya podrás logearte, con el nuevo password

Comment: Al parecer no agregan el archivo config.inc.php, hay que crearlo. Seguí los pasos de instalación desde la carpeta doc/html/index.html. Apollo tu respuesta aunque no la probé :)